# Uppercase only last 4 characters in a string

Tags: ruby

How can I make only the last 4 characters in a string uppercase in Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 'string'
"#{s[0..-5]}#{s[-4..-1].upcase}" # => stRING
```

To prevent an error with strings shorter than 4 characters you can do this:

```
s = 'foo'
s.length > 4 ? "#{s[0..-5]}#{s[-4..-1].upcase}" : s.upcase # => FOO
```

Check out the [Ruby API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "let's upcase last 4 letters"
length = str.length
str = str[0..(length-5)] + str[(length-4)..length].upcase
# let's upcase last 4 letTERS
```

Comment: You don't have to get the length of the string first. You can simply do `str[0..-5] + str[-4,4].upcase`. You may still want to check that original string is at least 4 characters long though.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

```
s = "string"
s.size > 3 ? s[0..-5]+s[-4..-1].upcase : s.upcase # "stRING"
```